# Does the index need rebuilding when not batch inserting data?

Tags: mysql, indexing, rebuild

Let me rephrase the question:

Is it vital for the `/*! */` lines, in the SQL file below, to exist when inserting data using individual INSERT statements?

This is the contents of the file now:

```
LOCK TABLES `adv_links` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `adv_links` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `adv_links` VALUES (13,'photoreal','http://w.otoreal.tk','',14,'something','something, something',64,0,1,1,'',0,'',1277754393,1277754393,0,0,0,'85.72.100.18',0,0,0,'');
INSERT INTO `adv_links` VALUES (4,'something cirocco', 'ttp://ww.roccoh.t/','',16,'something.','',86,0,1,1,'',0,'achille',1259843781,1259843781,2714,0,0,'91.132.75.249',0,0,0,'');
INSERT INTO `adv_links` VALUES (5,'somethingasco','htp://w.vsco.b/ge/gtpage.asp?i=0','',16,'somethingsco','sco',113,0,1,1,'',0,'achille',1259843935,1259843935,2714,0,0,'91.132.75.249',0,0,0,'');
INSERT INTO `adv_links` VALUES (6,'something','http://w.ja.b/Default.aspx','',16,'somethingaga','',62,0,1,1,'',0,'achille',1259848860,1259848860,2714,0,0,'91.132.75.249',0,0,0,'');
INSERT INTO `adv_links` VALUES (7,'something','htp://w.arkorrier.com.tr/English/AC_urun.asp?ID=ACU36#','',16,'','',90,0,1,1,'',0,'achille',1259848962,1259848962,2714,0,0,'91.132.75.249',0,0,0,'');
-- omitted
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `adv_links` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I am asking this because when reaching the `/*!40000 ALTER TABLE adv_link ENABLE KEYS */;` line, MySQL goes and repairs the index by sort and it can't find enough space since the dataset is large enough to choke in the `tmpdir` while sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't disable and re-enable your keys, the keys will update dynamically with each `INSERT` statement (as they normally do).

This does not require writes to `tmpdir`, but is more slow.

You may drop these lines if you cannot increase temporary space used by `MySQL`, though it will slow down your import.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the suspicion.